# How to fix welcome message Embed Discord Bot JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to send a welcome message embed, but it says: "channel is not defined".

This is my code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Welcome")
    .setDescription(`Hi ${member}, Welcome to server`)
    .setImage('https://image.ibb.co/dNGVKz/Screenshot_1.png');
  channel.send({embed});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a channel. You can fetch a channel by ID and send the embed there with the following code:

```js
//Discord.js V13:
client.channels.cache.get(`CHANNELID`).send({ embeds: [embed] })

//Discord.jsV12 (deprecated)
client.channels.cache.get(`CHANNELID`).send(embed)
```

Comment: Now its say: client.channels.cache.get(...).send(...).setTitle is not a function

Comment: this is not supposed to replace all your code. Just replace the `channel.send...` line with the code I gave in my answer

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind upvoting my Answer with the up arrow and mark it as accepted with the ✔